# Rails 4.2 nested form attributes not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I cannot seem to get nested attributes to save to the database, though I can see the params in terminal. I am using Rails 4.2.

Here are my models:

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :hub
    has_many :accessories, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :accessories,
                         reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['material'].blank? },
                     allow_destroy: true
end                        

class Accessory < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :device
end
```

Here is the controller. I have my device model nested under user and hub model.

```
class DevicesController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @user = User.find_by(params[:user_id])
    @hub = Hub.find_by_title(params[:hub_id])
    @device = Device.find_by(id: params[:id])

  end

  def update
    @user = User.find_by(params[:user_id])
    @hub = Hub.find_by_title(params[:hub_id])
    @device = Device.find_by(id: params[:id])

    if @device.update_attributes(device_params)
        flash[:success] = "update successfully"
        redirect_to user_hub_device_path(@user, @hub, @device)
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
  end
  private

  def device_params
    params.require(:device).permit(:model, :hub_id, :resolution, :materials, :startcost, :take_online, :delivery_time, :unitcost, :color, :accessories, :accessories_attributes => [:id, :name, :cost, :color, :device_id, :_destroy])
  end 

end
```

Finally is my form.

```
<%= form_for([@user, @hub, @device]) do |f| %>
<fieldset>
    <div id="material">

      <%= f.fields_for :accessories do |a| %>
        <%= render 'devices/accessory', a: a %>
      <% end %>

    </div>
</fieldset>
```

The partial:

```
<div class="row">
   <%= a.collection_select :name, Material.all, :material, :material  %>   
   <%= a.text_field :cost, id: "right-label" %>
   <%= a.text_field :color, id: "right-label" %>
   <%= a.check_box :_destroy %>

</div>
```

Comment: Have you created instances (using build method) of Accessory so that you can edit it in the form?

Comment: Yes, I have several instances and they do show up for editing, but they just remain the same after I submit.

Comment: Any chance to get me the source repository to try different things? Is the id hidden field still generated?

Answer (score 0):

You are whitelisting `params[:device][:materials]` but you are checking `attributes['material'].blank?` (note the the s on the end). Which causes the nested attributes to be rejected.

Comment: Thanks bro. You remind me of that part. Actually, it's not material that caused the rejection. I change it to my accessory's attribute, and it works now.